# Submit form via ajax to another domain

Tags: jquery, cors

I need to submit a form via ajax (not json) to another domain but keep getting the error

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://some.other.domain/. Origin http://localhost:8081 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.`

Is there a way to "fix" this?

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "text/html",
    data: $("#surveyForm").serialize(),
    crossDomain: true,
    url: "http://some.other.domain",
    processData: false,
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    },
    success: function (response) {
    }
});
```

Comment: Do you own the other domain? If so you can add CORS headers to the response: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

Comment: Unfortunately I don't own the other domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best option might be to set up a [proxy server](http://developer.yahoo.com/javascript/howto-proxy.html). You can't use JSON-P because you are doing a form POST, and you can't use CORS because you don't control the headers on the remote domain.

Comment: Yep I think that's probably my best bet.

Answer (score 0):

I think for sending data to cross domain u have to use data type as JSONP. U cant post the whole form.My below code is working correctly for me(hope this will help u)

```
  $.ajax({ url: "MYURL",
    data: {
           paxMessage: JSON.stringify(paxMessage)
          },

    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

    dataType: "jsonp",

    success: function(data) {
              alert("Data Submitted successfully");
           },

    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
           alert(textStatus);
           }
       });
```